# FileField in nested serializer is holding a path, when updated throws error "The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form."

Tags: python, django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

I have created a nested serialiser and custome create and update methods in it. While POST(Create) methos i am not getting any error, but while Updating i am getting error "The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form.".

Model:

```
class SmsModelMaster(models.Model):
    SRNumber = models.CharField('Request Number', max_length=50, blank=True, unique=True)
    SRState = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='Requested', 
    blank=False, null=True, unique=False)
    PreviousSRState = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=False)
    SRCategory_SMS = models.ForeignKey(ServiceBucket, related_name='SRCategory_SMS', 
    blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    SRName_SMS = models.ForeignKey(ServiceBucket, related_name='SRName_SMS', blank=True, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    RequestType = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=False)
    RequesterName = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=False)
    RequestedOnBehalfOf = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    SMETSVersion = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    TPName = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)
    Expected_Completion_Time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True, 
    null=True)
    Request_Time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, null=True, blank=True)
    CompletionDate = models.DateField(default=timezone.now, null=True, blank=True)
    MetersetUseEndDate = models.DateField(default=timezone.now, blank=True, null=True)
    ActivitySummary = models.CharField(max_length=3000, blank=True, null=True)
    DocumentUpload = models.FileField(upload_to='Support_Request/SMS_Model/', default=None, 
    null=True, blank=True)
    Assigned_To = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.SRNumber

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "SMS Administrator"
```

Serializer:

```
class sms_adminserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    commentdata = sms_commentserializer(many=True, required=False)
    metersetdata = sms_metersetserializer(many=True, required=False)
    devicedata = sms_deviceserializer(many=True, required=False)
    Expected_Completion_Time = serializers.DateTimeField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = SmsModelMaster
        fields = ('SRNumber', 'SRState', 'PreviousSRState', 'SRCategory_SMS', 'SRName_SMS', 
        'RequestType', 'RequesterName', 'RequestedOnBehalfOf','SMETSVersion', 'TPName', 
        'Expected_Completion_Time, 'Request_Time','CompletionDate', 'MetersetUseEndDate', 
        'ActivitySummary', 'DocumentUpload', 'commentdata', 'metersetdata', 
        'devicedata','Assigned_To')
        read_only_fields = ('Request_Time', )


    def create(self, validated_data):
        commentdata = validated_data.pop('commentdata')
        metersetdata = validated_data.pop('metersetdata')
        devicedata = validated_data.pop('devicedata')

        smsdata = SmsModelMaster.objects.create(**validated_data)
        count = 0
        endcount = 0

        for evcomments in commentdata:
            evcomments.pop('SRNum', None)
            evcomments.pop('CommentState', None)
            CommentModel.objects.create(**evcomments, SRNum=smsdata, CommentState=smsdata)
        for evmetersetdata in metersetdata:
            evmetersetdata.pop('SRName', None)
            meterda =MeterSetModelSMSAdmin.objects.create(**evmetersetdata, SRName=smsdata)
            tobeuseddevicedata = devicedata
            endcount = endcount + meterda.Device_length
            deviceslicedata = tobeuseddevicedata[count:endcount]
            for evdevicedata in deviceslicedata:
                evdevicedata.pop('SR_Name', None)
                evdevicedata.pop('MetsersetName', None)
                DeviceModelSMSAdmin.objects.create(**evdevicedata, SR_Name=smsdata, 
                MetsersetName=meterda)
                count = count + 1
                endcount = endcount
        return smsdata

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        comments = validated_data.pop('commentdata')
        metersetdata = validated_data.pop('metersetdata')
        devicedata = validated_data.pop('devicedata')

        instance.SRState = validated_data.get("SRState", instance.SRState)
        instance.PreviousSRState = validated_data.get("PreviousSRState", 
        instance.PreviousSRState)
        instance.Expected_Completion_Time = validated_data.get("Expected_Completion_Time",
        instance.Expected_Completion_Time)
        instance.save()
       

        id_list = []
        comm = CommentModel.objects.filter(SRNum=instance)
        test = sms_commentserializer(comm, many=True)
        for ev in test.data:
            id_list.append(ev['id'])

        # take all id for the meterset table
        met_list = []
        metset = MeterSetModelSMSAdmin.objects.filter(SRName=instance)
        qmetset = sms_metersetserializer(metset, many=True)
        for mev in qmetset.data:
            met_list.append(mev['id'])

        # take all id for the device table
        dev_list = []
        devset = DeviceModelSMSAdmin.objects.filter(SR_Name=instance)
        qdevset = sms_deviceserializer(devset, many=True)
        for dev in qdevset.data:
            dev_list.append(dev['id'])

        # comments operations
        comm_choices = []
        for comment in comments:
            if "id" in comment.keys():
                if CommentModel.objects.filter(id=comment["id"]).exists():
                    c = CommentModel.objects.get(id=comment["id"])
                    c.Comments = comment.get('Comments', c.Comments)
                    c.CommentType = comment.get('CommentType', c.CommentType)
                    c.CommentedBy = comment.get('CommentedBy', c.CommentedBy)
                    c.save()
                    comm_choices.append(c.id)
                else:
                    continue
            else:
                comment.pop('SRNum', None)
                comment.pop('CommentState', None)
                c = CommentModel.objects.create(**comment, SRNum=instance, 
                CommentState=instance)
                comm_choices.append(c.id)

        for ev in id_list:
            if ev not in comm_choices:
                com = CommentModel.objects.get(id=ev)
                com.delete()

        # Meterset operations
        meterset_choices = []
        for metsett in metersetdata:
            if "id" in metsett.keys():
                if MeterSetModelSMSAdmin.objects.filter(id=metsett["id"]).exists():
                    m = MeterSetModelSMSAdmin.objects.get(id=metsett["id"])
                    m.TestPhase = metsett.get('TestPhase', m.TestPhase)
                    m.Test_Phase_info_correct = metsett.get('Test_Phase_info_correct', 
                    m.Test_Phase_info_correct)
                    m.Updated_Test_Phase = metsett.get('Updated_Test_Phase', 
                    m.Updated_Test_Phase)
                    m.ReallocationToTP = metsett.get('ReallocationToTP', m.ReallocationToTP)
                    m.ReallocatedTPName = metsett.get('ReallocatedTPName', 
                    m.ReallocatedTPName)
                    m.Set_Migration = metsett.get('Set_Migration', m.Set_Migration)
                    m.SMETS1_Reference_Number = metsett.get('SMETS1_Reference_Number', 
                    m.SMETS1_Reference_Number)
                    m.Alternative_Meterset = metsett.get('Alternative_Meterset', 
                    m.Alternative_Meterset)
                    m.Alternative_Meterset_Name = metsett.get('Alternative_Meterset_Name', 
                    m.Alternative_Meterset_Name)
                    m.DCC_Approval = metsett.get('DCC_Approval', m.DCC_Approval)
                    m.Actioned = metsett.get('Actioned', m.Actioned)
                    m.Action_Reason = metsett.get('Action_Reason', m.Action_Reason)
                    m.Installer = metsett.get('Installer', m.Installer)
                    m.Install_Verification_Doneby = metsett.get('Install_Verification_Doneby',
                                                                m.Install_Verification_Doneby)
                    m.Inventory_Team = metsett.get('Inventory_Team', m.Inventory_Team)
                    m.New_Lab_Room = metsett.get('New_Lab_Room', m.New_Lab_Room)
                    m.Updated_MeterSet_Name = metsett.get('Updated_MeterSet_Name', 
                    m.Updated_MeterSet_Name)
                    m.New_Lab_Position = metsett.get('New_Lab_Position', m.New_Lab_Position)
                    m.Inprogress_Remarks = metsett.get('Inprogress_Remarks', 
                    m.Inprogress_Remarks)
                    m.Registered_SMSO = metsett.get('Registered_SMSO', m.Registered_SMSO)
                    m.Devices_Decommissioned = metsett.get('Devices_Decommissioned', 
                    m.Devices_Decommissioned)
                    m.Attach_Evidence = metsett.get('Attach_Evidence', m.Attach_Evidence)
                    m.GPF_replaced_ACB = metsett.get('GPF_replaced_ACB', m.GPF_replaced_ACB)
                    m.Actual_Efforts = metsett.get('Actual_Efforts', m.Actual_Efforts)
                    m.Activity_Completed = metsett.get('Activity_Completed', 
                    m.Activity_Completed)
                    m.UnInstaller = metsett.get('UnInstaller', m.UnInstaller)
                    m.Actioned = metsett.get('Actioned', m.Actioned)
                    m.save()
                    meterset_choices.append(m.id)
                else:
                    continue
            else:
                metsett.pop('SRName', None)
                m = MeterSetModelSMSAdmin.objects.create(**metsett, SRName=instance)
                meterset_choices.append(m.id)

        for re in met_list:
            if re not in meterset_choices:
                met = MeterSetModelSMSAdmin.objects.get(id=re)
                met.delete()
        return instance
```

API JSON Data Sample:

```
{
    "SRNumber": "SR-129",
    "SRState": "Pending Approval",
    "PreviousSRState": "New Request",
    "SRCategory_SMS": 19,
    "SRName_SMS": 19,
    "RequestType": "Mothball Out",
    "RequesterName": "admin",
    "RequestedOnBehalfOf": "admin",
    "SMETSVersion": "SSSSSS",
    "TPName": "XXXXXXX",
    "Expected_Completion_Time": "2021-12-21T10:23:07.643427",
    "Request_Time": "2021-12-21T10:23:07.643436",
    "CompletionDate": "2021-12-22",
    "MetersetUseEndDate": "2021-12-27",
    "ActivitySummary": "test",
    "DocumentUpload": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/Support_Request/SMS_Model/SR- 
     129_Mothball_Out_211221_102307.zip",
}
```

While i send update, i am not updating "DocumentUpload" this filed but , i am getting below error.

```
{
    "DocumentUpload": [
        "The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form."
    ]
}
```

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: If you are trying to upload a file you need to make the request with `multipart/form-data` content type, not as JSON

Comment: multipart/form-data is used on html forms and it is working fine, i am receving the uploaded documnets on request.FILES.getlist('DocumentUpload[]') and i am zipping it and sending it through my JSON, this is working fine. But i am facing issue only durig Update